# how to get gmail mails in my listView

Tags: android, android-asynctask, gmail, email-client

```
protected Void doInBackground(String[]... urls) {

            String userPass[]=urls[0];
            String user=userPass[0];
            String password=userPass[1];

            try {
                Properties props = System.getProperties();

                props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
                session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);              
                store = session.getStore("imaps");

                store.connect(mailhost, user, password); 

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
}
```

this is my code and am not able to move after store.connect(..). even in debug mode.

Comment: make sure you have define internet permissions in your application Manifest

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_CONTENT_PROVIDER" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


I AM USING ABOVE PERMISSIONS

Comment: ok my code is working fine, i am storing mails in Message array, and i am using getSubject, getFrom to get the sender and subject, but how to get the body of mail....?